# DNScrypt proxy not working

Tags: dns, dnscrypt-proxy

I've installed DNScrypt proxy from https://github.com/opendns/dnscrypt-proxy/downloads and installed it under Ubuntu 11.10 x64. 
I started the proxy by

```
sudo /usr/sbin/dnscrypt-proxy --daemonize
```

syslog states

```
dnscrypt-proxy[2615]: dnscrypt-proxy is ready: proxying from [127.0.0.1] to [208.67.220.220]
```

I set the dns to localhost and restart the connection by gui.
But the local dns can not be reached:

```
dnscrypt-proxy[2615]: dnscrypt-proxy is ready: proxying from [127.0.0.1] to [208.67.220.220]
```

netstat

```
PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN          2231/dnscrypt-proxy
```

Someone has an idea?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Refer to the [official instructions](https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-proxy/wiki/Installation-Debian-Ubuntu).

Answer (score 4):

At least for Ubuntu 12.04 the issue is local DNS cache running on 127.0.0.1 (dnsmasq). Webupd8.org has a walk through and a script to change the local listening IP to 127.0.0.2.

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/encrypt-dns-traffic-in-linux-with.html

Scroll down to the Ubuntu section. I have it working for both 11.10 x64 and 12.04 x64 using their script. Initially it was not working on 11.10 but a full reboot resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the DNS servers to: 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo /usr/sbin/dnscrypt-proxy --daemonize --tcp-only
```

I think there is a bug in UDP connection to dnscrypt

More info

https://github.com/opendns/dnscrypt-proxy/issues/53

[connection timeout after 60 seconds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291109/connection-timeout-after-60-seconds)