# connection timeout after 60 seconds

Tags: networking, timeout

I have installed [DNSCrypt](http://dnscrypt.org/) on Ubuntu Linux 10.04.1 x86_64 and it worked

```
nslookup facebook.com 127.0.0.2
Server:         127.0.0.2
Address:        127.0.0.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   facebook.com
Address: 173.252.110.27
```

but **after about 60 seconds**

```
nslookup facebook.com 127.0.0.2
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

The deamon is already running . It's like something by OS prevents /usr/local/sbin/dnscrypt-proxy to accept connections .
What can do this ?

Edit 1 :
The problem **only** appears on **UDP** .

query udp port

```
dig @127.0.0.2 +notcp facebook.com

; <<>> DiG 9.7.0-P1 <<>> @127.0.0.2 +notcp facebook.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

query tcp port

```
dig @127.0.0.2 +tcp facebook.com

; <<>> DiG 9.7.0-P1 <<>> @127.0.0.2 +tcp facebook.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 63984
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;facebook.com.                  IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
facebook.com.           889     IN      A       173.252.110.27

;; Query time: 516 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.2#53(127.0.0.2)
;; WHEN: Sun May  5 22:34:14 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 46
```

Comment: This still happens?